# TextRange is not selected/highlighted in WebBrowser control

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, range, webbrowser-control

I try to select (highlight) a text in a webbrowser control, I used the following code. When the user selects a word and click on a button the rest of the sentence (in this code) must be selected and highlighted, but nothing is highlighted.

The `range.htmlText` shows an HTML containing the parent elements and the sentence from the selection start to the end but nothing is highlighted and `execCommand` just runs on the manually selected word!

```
if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
{
    IHTMLDocument2 doc =
        webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
    IHTMLBodyElement body = doc.body as IHTMLBodyElement;
    if (body != null)
    {
        IHTMLTxtRange range;
        if (doc.selection != null)
        {               
            if (doc.selection.type == "Text")
            {                        
               range = doc.selection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
               range.moveEnd("sentence"); //word, character,....
               range.select();
               webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("cut", true, null);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `body` element `visibility` was set to `hidden`.

Selection highlighting may not work in `WebBrowser` control if the `body` element or a parent element of the `selection` is invisible (`style.visibility = "hidden"`)